# sed equivalent of perl -pe

Tags: perl, sed

I'm looking for an equivalent of `perl -pe`. Ideally, it would be replace with `sed` if it's possible. Any help is highly appreciated.

The code is:

```
perl -pe 's/^\[([^\]]+)\].*$/$1/g'
```

Comment: If you don't include the Perl code, we can't help you. There's no general way to translate Perl to sed.

Comment: remember `bash` != `sed`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$ echo '[foo] 123' | perl -pe 's/^\[([^\]]+)\].*$/$1/g'
foo

$ echo '[foo] 123' | sed -E 's/^\[([^]]+)\].*$/\1/'
foo
```

- `sed` by default accepts code from command line, so `-e` isn't needed (though it can be used)
- printing the pattern space is default, so `-p` isn't needed and `sed -n` is similar to `perl -n`
- `-E` is used here to be as close as possible to Perl regex. `sed` supports BRE and ERE (not as feature rich as Perl) and even that differs from implementation to implementation.

  - with BRE, the command for this example would be: `sed 's/^\[\([^]]*\)\].*$/\1/'`
- `\` isn't special inside character class unless it is an escape sequence like `\t`, `\x27` etc
- backreferences use `\N` format (and limited to maximum `9`)
- Also note that `g` flag isn't needed in either case, as you are using line anchors